# Using Ctypes to Configure DLL functions

Tags: ctypes

I have a shared library file (windows DLL) that contains about 50 functions.  The functions in the DLL have return values and arguments that need to be configured using .argtypes and .restype.  I want to create a module that I can import into my python programs that does the configuration.  For example -- the following code works fine in my program (Open, Close, Save are example functions of "mydll":

```
import ctypes as ct
mylib = ct.cdll.LoadLibrary("mydll")

mylib.Open.argtypes = [ct.c_char_p] 
mylib.Open.restype = ct.c_int

mylib.Close.argtypes = [ct.c_int] 
mylib.Close.restype = ct.c_int

mylib.Save.argtypes = [ct.c_int] 
mylib.Save.restype = ct.c_int

#continue for 50 or so more functions
```

I would like to create a package or module that I can import for this code, instead of including it at the beginning of each program that will use "mydll".  What is the correct approach in Python?

Comment: Please reformat your question so that it follows the [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines. What do you mean by "*configure*"? Yes you have to specify them all, but indeed you could do a parser (or use an existing one) that would do that automatically, based on the *.dll*'s header file.

Comment: downvote, til the question meets all the criteria (will retract afterwards).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I have tried editing to see if I can make the question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by writing a binding.py file that includes a function for each function in the library, mydll.

So binding.py looks like this:

```
import ctypes as ct
mylib = ct.cdll.LoadLibrary("mydll")

def func1():
    mylib.func1().argtypes = [ct.c_char_p] 
    mylib.func1().restype = ct.c_int
    return mylib.func1()

def func2():
    mylib.func2().argtypes = [ct.c_int, ct.c_char_p, ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)]
    mylib.func2().restype = ct.c_int
    return mylib.func2()

def func3():
    mylib.func3().argtypes = []
    mylib.func3().restype = ct.c_int
    return mylib.func3()

The fundamental data types for the argument and return values can be found here:
[cytpes fundamental data types][1]


  [1]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html
```